# Using Angular 2. I updated my tsconfig.json, how do I actually make sure the settings apply?

Tags: typescript, angular

I added `paths` to my config as such, and I'm not sure how to "save" these changes.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./*"]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSources": true
  },

  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "typings.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

I am using visual studio code for my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused on your question but to "save" changes simply use the save shortcut by hitting "CTRL" and "S" at the same time. If items are not saved there will be an * on the tab that you have opened in VS.